# Installing pytesser on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, tesseract

I would like to install pytesser on my raspberry pi to use an OCR. I have no idea how to do that as I can't find it in apt-cache.

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0):

cd /home/pi
mkdir pytesser
cd pytesser
wget http://pytesser.googlecode.com/files/pytesser_v0.0.1.zip
unzip pytesser_v0.0.1.zip

and done